# Firebase get Current User null in new activity after logged in user

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After Successful log in my SignIn activity intent to BloodBank activity and the activity check if there any Currentuser or not.
In my case when it comes to BloodBank activity after log in, the method returning current user is null always
Is there any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Here is my SignIn Activity.java

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

Button signIn,forgetPass;
TextView backToSignUp,number,password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    signIn=findViewById(R.id.signInButtonId);
    forgetPass=findViewById(R.id.forgetPassButtonId);
    backToSignUp=findViewById(R.id.signUpBack);
    number=findViewById(R.id.signInNumberId);
    password=findViewById(R.id.signInPasswordId);


    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String _phone = number.getText().toString().trim();
            final String _password = password.getText().toString().trim();

            if (_phone.isEmpty()) {
                number.setError("Enter Your Phone Number");
                number.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (_password.isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Enter a password");
                password.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BloodBank_users");
            Query checkUser=reference.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(_phone);

            checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        number.setError(null);
                        number.setEnabled(true);

                        String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(_phone).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                        if (passwordFromDB.equals(_password)) {

                            password.setError(null);
                            password.setEnabled(true);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BloodBankMain.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            password.setError("Wrong Password Or User Name");
                            password.requestFocus();
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        number.setError("This Number Is Not Registered");
                        number.requestFocus();
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });


        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my BloodBank.Java

```
public class BloodBank extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood_bank);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public  void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user!=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(BloodBank.this, BloodBankMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(BloodBank.this,SignIn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }



    };


}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}



}
```

Comment: Which method returns null?

Comment: In BloodBank.java "OnAuthStateChange"

Comment: What exactly inside it is null?

Comment: After loged in the current user shouldn't null but it's returning null i mean no user loged in

Comment: So make sure the uses is logged in, and try again.

Comment: Yes I tried after logged in but it's return null user that's why o posted it here

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).